# LightSwitch HTML Client - Select Modal Picker value from code

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I need to select item in a Modal Picker from JS. I already got the value in DOM.

Can somebody give me a hint or example how to do it?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by entity on create method. That method can be created when u click on Server - Database - Table name, then choose HTML Client and create new "created event". Then you can set default values in a new created item.

ie:

```
myapp.Leistungserfassung.created = function (entity) {
var now = new Date();
entity.CreatedTime = now;
entity.UpdatedTime = now;
entity.Pause = 30;
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.Database.SomePickerAttribute
    .top(1)
    .execute().then(function (result) {
        entity.SomePickerAttribute= result.results[0];
    });
```

};

myapp.activeDataWorkspace.Database.SomePickerAttribute.top(1)

- this will load first record (u can specify more then 1)

.then()

- will execute after AJAX call retrieve item from the server

The rest is up to you.

If you have situation that you need to put default values to eq. "filter" on a list screen. You can do it same way as example above, (on screen create) but this time put needed value into property that is binded to your picker. Only problem is that your label won't get updated. This can be solved with little jQuery.

For example:

```
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.LeistungserfassungScreenItemsData.LeistungserfassungDateFilters.top(1).execute()
    .then(function (result) {
        $('#datePicker')
            .find('.id-element')
            .html(result.results[0].Text);
    });
```

Remember to put ID to your picker element. This can be done on `_postRender` event with this little command: `$(element).find('.id-element').attr('id', 'datePicker')`

I'm still beginner so I'm sure there are other better ways to do this. But for now this are only ones I know. And I could say that they work OK.